# Custom Check box click slow in edge browser with ngFor Angular 5

Tags: ionic3, angular5, microsoft-edge, ngfor

I'm binding elements using *ngFor in the UI. The element contains the custom checkbox that checks the value based on the condition from the data example, **item.isSelected= true**  in the sense. If I click the checkbox I'm changing only the selected checkbox data to **"item.isSelected= true"** inside the modifier array. If anything I'm changing in the array It will automatically reflect in UI too. because data is bonded to ngFor it again try to rebind data to UI. But it will take long too bind values and check the check box in UI(Only in edge browser others like chrome, firefox doing well). Please give me some suggestion to resolve this one.

**Data Example**

```
[
 {
   body: "laudantium enim quasi est quidem magnam voluptate ipsam eos↵tempora 
           quo necessitatibus↵dolor quam autem quasi↵reiciendis "
   email: "Eliseo@gardner.biz"
   id: 1
   isSelected: false
   name: "id labore ex et quam laborum"
   postId: 1
 }
.
.
.
upto 2500 objects

]
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  commentArray: any = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http) {
    debugger
    this.getdata();
  }

  getdata() {
    //getting the data from API here
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').
      subscribe(data => {
        this.commentArray = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        //pass this to set data to set isSelected flag
        this.setData(this.commentArray);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  setData(data) {
    //here setting the isSelected flag
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i]['isSelected'] = false;
    }
    //getting only 500 data so copy the old data and push to array
    for (let i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
      let d = data[0];
      d.isSelected = false;
      data.push(d);
    }
    this.commentArray = data;
    //Total data now 2500
  }

  changeCheckbox(index){
    debugger
    console.time("Performance");
    for(let i=0;i<this.commentArray.length;i++){
      if(index == i){
        this.commentArray[i].isSelected = true;
      }else{
        this.commentArray[i].isSelected = false;
      }
    }
    console.timeEnd("Performance");
  }

}
```

**home.html**

```
 <div>
    <ul *ngFor="let item of commentArray;let i = index;">
      <li (click)="changeCheckbox(i)">
        <span>{{i}}</span>&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" [checked]="item.isSelected" >
        <span>{{item.name}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please check your code, the data Model and the model in the UI contains different properties. Besides, I suggest you check the data array, whether it contains too many items? Also, you could check the logic, whether it spends too much time. And you could also use F12 developer tools to check the performance. Finally, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because, According to your code, I create a sample on my side, it seems that everything works well.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT Thank you for your comments. Sorry about the wrong data model. I have changed it now.
For your question,
"whether it contains too many items?"
yes, Data size is huge.
Before checked the checkbox we handled some conditions. If those conditions satisfy only I'm
checking the checkbox. I verified my logic, the code execution time that execute within the 40ms.
Chrome and browser rendering it quickly but edge only taking time.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're only experiencing problems in Microsoft Edge (and I don't have edge), I can only guess at a few performance optimizations for you:

```js
export class HomePage {

  commentArray: any = [];
  selectedComment: number | null = null;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private http: Http) {
    this.getdata();
  }

  getdata() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments').
      subscribe(data => {
        // Only getting the first 500 items
        this.commentArray = JSON.parse(data['_body']).slice(0,500);          
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  selectComment(index: number) {
    this.selectedComment = index;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul *ngFor="let item of commentArray;let i = index;">
    <li (click)="selectComment(i)">
      <span>{{i}}</span>&nbsp;
      <input type="radio" [checked]="selectedCheckbox === index" >
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

The largest performance improvement would probably come from switching the component's change detection to `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. With so many items in the viewport, it could simply be a change detection issue.

You could also use the angular cdk [VirtualForOf](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#virtual-scrolling) component to reduce the number of items the browser needs to render at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. Now you are assigned ''[checked]" value while clicking the button. So the value will update instantly. Let me tell you another scenario If I need the do some conditions in the background (like I did in my code at the top) and then only I can check the checkbox. In that time this code will not work. Because this code will check the checkbox instantly. If my condition false in the sense i don't want to check the checkbox, In that time checked checkbox will disappear..this will not look good.

Comment: @venishk why can't you just have the `click` event call a method which does whatever logic necessary before setting (or not setting) `selectedComment = index`?